# Magento 2 how to access external JS variables and functions in my html template?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

I need to access to an external javascript variables and functions so the template does not throws error.

I have my **template.html** template doing this:

```
<!-- ko template: "Vendor_ManualShipping/external-template" --><!-- /ko -->
```

the external template that I wan't to use in my template is like this:

**external-template.html**

```
<div class="manualshipping-container__selectors">
        <select 
        name="region" 
        id="region_checkout" 
        class="input-text" 
        title="region_checkout"
        data-bind="options: availableStates,
                   value: selectedState,
                   optionsCaption: 'Selecciona tu Estado'"
        ></select>
        <select 
        name="municipio" 
        id="municipio_checkout" 
        class="input-text" 
        title="municipio_checkout"
        data-bind="options: availableCities,
                   value: selectedCity,
                   optionsCaption: 'Selecciona tu Ciudad'"
        ></select>

        <a class="action primary continue btn-show" data-bind="click: getPharmaciesInfo" href="#">
            <span translate="'Buscar'"/>
        </a>
    </div>
```

When I use **template.html**  it throws an error saying availableStates is undefined, of course because I have no **availableStates** in my js, but then how can I use the javascript of the external template?

I have tried this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'mage/url',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Vendor_ManualShipping/js/view/external-js'

], function ($,Component, ko, quote, url, modal, manualShipping) {
    'use strict';
```

This did not worked.

So how then can I have an external template working on another template?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old post... did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Drew yes, I changed it to a script-mage-init-x component, and you can pass variables to the component from the .phtml template, then on that same template you can render the .html template previous filled with the variables on the js component, makes sense?

Comment: it does yes... thanks for the followup.  TL;DR... we ended up not needing to continue development down this process so I was never able to see it through to fruition.  :-(  I appreciate the feedback and hope to test it again in the future.  Have a wonderful holiday season @Oscar!